# Header information of `yarn top` command

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

The usual `top` command on UNIX and Mac OS, was extended to hadoop in its recent versions, some information about it is given [here](https://hadoopsters.net/2017/06/30/cluster-usage-with-yarn-top/).
It has the following headers,

`APPLICATIONID USER TYPE QUEUE #CONT #RCONT VCORES RVCORES MEM RMEM VCORESECS MEMSECS %PROGR TIME NAME`

I was wondering what `#RCCONT` `RVCORES` and `RMEM` mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R stands for reserved. So they can be interpreted as:

```
#RCONT  - reserved containers
RVCORES - reserved virtual cores
RMEM    - reserved memory
```

Comment: And VCORESECS =?

Comment: The number of virtual cores * total time in seconds the application has been running.